# GAE instances failing to start (deployment fine, instances not starting overnight - suspect unadmitted outage)

Tags: google-app-engine

Overnight, a critical application for us (lightweight, but central to the business) wouldn't load for several hours. There's no mention of GAE having any issues, we didn't push any code or update anything. In the logs, however, I see four entries like this:

> ERROR 2023-12-03T10:17:14.322254Z The request failed because the instance could not start successfully
> ERROR 2023-12-03T11:06:19.120908Z [protoPayload.method: GET] [protoPayload.status: 500] [protoPayload.latency: 1 ms] [protoPayload.userAgent: Safari 15.6.4] /

To me, this suggests the cluster was out of healthy worker nodes, or something similar?